# Python Selenium - Wait until an element is visible

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait, blocking

I know about the solution with

`elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reply-button"))).click()`

But here you would wait 20 seconds and then it would either load the element in a variable or throw an exception.

Is there any `blocking` solution which stops the program until the element is visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `WebDriverWait` will not wait 20 seconds.
It returns web element matching the passed locator, `.reply-button` css_selector in your case, at the moment Selenium detects that element presence.
It will wait for the defined timeout period only if no element found.
As about the element visibility, there is a similar expected condition waiting for element to be visible, like this:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.reply-button')))
```

This will block the flow execution exactly until the element located by `.reply-button` css_selector is found to be visible or for the timeout, the first of the above.